# Hierarchical Depth Level logic in JSON data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Just want to know your code logic using javascript in this problem.
I want to put a depth level tracking in my hierarchical data. The data can have more layers.

This is my sample data

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k56fQ.png)

I want to put a **depth** attribute in each

[Edited Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjdVz.png)

Sample Data

```
[{
"id": 1,
"label": "System",
"parent_id": null,
"description": "System Manager",
"children": [{
    "id": 2,
    "label": "base",
    "parent_id": 1,
    "description": "Base Manager",
    "children": [{
        "id": 3,
        "label": "Menus",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "description": "menu manager",

    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "label": "Roles",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "description": "Role Manager",

    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "label": "Users",
        "parent_id": 2,
        "description": "User Manager",

    }]
}]
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Customs",
    "parent_id": null,
    "description": "Custom Manager",
    "children": [{
        "id": 7,
        "label": "CustomList",
        "parent_id": 6,
        "description": "CustomList",

    }]
}
```

Comment: Please provide the data in a way that people can use your data in their solutions. And please provide at least what you have tried! Thanks.

Comment: There are some errors in your json -- I guess from manually building your json -- take a look at my answer and you'll have the correct data. I suggest you to use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ for checking your json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But there you go. I've boiled down your data to a simple example. As you can see Iam using a recursive function which will be incremented with each call to the next level.

```js
var example = [{
"id": 1,
"label": "System",
"parent_id": null,
"description": "System Manager",
"children": [{
"id": 2,
"label": "base",
"parent_id": 1,
"description": "Base Manager",
"children": [{
    "id": 3,
    "label": "Menus",
    "parent_id": 2,
    "description": "menu manager"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "label": "Roles",
    "parent_id": 2,
    "description": "Role Manager",

},
{
    "id": 5,
    "label": "Users",
    "parent_id": 2,
    "description": "User Manager"
}]
}]
},
{
"id": 6,
"label": "Customs",
"parent_id": null,
"description": "Custom Manager",
"children": [{
    "id": 7,
    "label": "CustomList",
    "parent_id": 6,
    "description": "CustomList"
}]
}];

var res = document.getElementById("res");

var addDepth = function(json, depth){
  return json.map(e => {
    e.depth = depth;
  
    if(e.children){
      e.children = addDepth(e.children, depth + 1);
    }
    
    return e;
  });
}

res.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(addDepth(example, 0), undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="res"></pre>
```

Comment: Sorry for the wrong format of json data. I like how you create your function, it is much better than what I did haha. I will just use yours . Thank you very much

Comment: It would be cool if you would provide your approach. This will help you, because people will tell you the difference to theirs and yours, wich is an awesome way to learn things.